# Remove extra blank lines from SyntaxHighlighter

Tags: javascript, syntaxhighlighter

I'm using SyntaxHighlighter in my blogger blog. But since few days it adds extra blank lines in my code. It only happens to new posts only. Can anyone please tell me how to remove these extra blank lines. I saw similar question. But it does not clearly answered. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we just copy and paste from windows notepad the blogger adds `<br/>` tags twice for `cr` and `lf`. So don't just copy and paste from notepad. Use blogger draft editor if it is really wanted.

Answer (score 3):

This not exactly an issue with the SyntaxHighlighter - recently the blogger adds the `<br />` tag for the ENTER.

Answer (score 2):

Or use HTML encoder. There are some sites that encode HTML. Use them before posting to blog.

Answer (score 0):

Use the newest version of the syntaxhighlighter